# Calendar Object Clone method

Tags: java, calendar

```
public class CalendarTest {

    private Calendar cal;

    public void setCalendar(Calendar cal){
        this.cal = (Calendar) cal.clone();   (1)
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        CalendarTest obj = new CalendarTest();
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //cal.setSomething;  (2)

            }
        }).start();
        obj.setCalendar(cal);
    }
}
```

clone() is called on cal object at (1) and at same time if state of cal is changed at (2), how will the clone behave. Like if one thread is cloning the fields of a calendar object and if other thread is working on writing to the same calendar object, will this result in an inconsistent Calendar object.

How can i handle scenarios of this kind?

Thread creation in the main method is just an example, client code would generally call the setCalendar() method.

Comment: it would be undefined, which ever gets pickedup first goes in

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour would be non-deterministic. Sometimes the clone will contain the copy of the fields before the changes at (2), sometimes the clone will contain the copy of the fields after the changes at (2) and sometimes it might contain only some of the changes at (2).

Use at [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or similar to make the behviour deterministic.